# can a java object call native function in this situation?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Java can call native function using JNI. It means I can run a JVM in my C++ program and construct java object by JNI with pointer only. And In this java object, native function can be called to access data in running C++ program. It runs successful.

But, If I just run C++ program and give the pointer of one object to java program. In java, can I use this pointer to construct many object to call native function in C++? The difference is I do not construct java object in JNI and just get pointer of object in C++, then In java I call native function to access data in C++ using JNI. The data is stored in the running C++ program.

So can it be possible? May C++ program have some protection? So I can't access its data by pointer of an object?

Comment: From your question I get the feeling that it is unclear to you what excatly JNI is: From Java perspective think of JNI like a translation layer written in c/c++ which translates native functions and data into something Java understands (and the other direction). This JNI layer is not automatically generated, instead you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I found I thought JNI in the wrong situation. I know what can be done by JNI, but ignore something important.

The question I want to ask is Whether I can convert the pointer of object in C++ to a java object and call its native function to access the data of object in C++. In fact, I need to create JVM in C++ process to convert the pointer to Java or just call native function in Java process. And there is no way to do this when they are two process, which means I run a C++ process and give its pointer of one object to another running Java process, then I want to access data in C++ process by calling native function in Java process.

One process holds its own memory resource and cannot be accessed by the other via its native function call (JNI). Process can communicate by many methods such as sockets.

Answer (score 0):

From Java, you can only call the C++ functions that were built for JNI. On the other hand, any JNI function in the C++ dynamic library can be called from Java, and a malicious Java program can reverse engineer your JNI and use it to exploit some vulnerability in your C++ code.